# Deleting multiple selected items in custom listview dosn't work with ImageButton

Tags: android, listview, imagebutton

It's very necessary for me. I am trying to create a `delete multiple selected items ListView`.The code is running right but when I add an `ImageButton` to custom_list_row.layout it's not working. I don't know about the problem. Maybe there is the same question but I didn't find it.

Code:

After I use

```
smsList.setAdapter(customListViewAdapter);
```

trying to use this code to delete selected items

```
smsList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
smsList.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {
        final int checkedCount = smsList.getCheckedItemCount();
        // Set the CAB title according to total checked items
        mode.setTitle(checkedCount + " Selected");
        // Calls toggleSelection method from ListViewAdapter Class
        customListViewAdapter.toggleSelection(position);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.delete_menu_option, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.delete:
                // call getSelectedIds method from customListViewAdapter
                SparseBooleanArray selected = customListViewAdapter.getSelectedIds();
                // Captures all selected ids with a loop
                for (int i = (selected.size() - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
                    if (selected.valueAt(i)) {
                        SmsClass selectedListItem = (SmsClass) customListViewAdapter.getItem(selected.keyAt(i));
                        // Remove selected items using ids
                        customListViewAdapter.remove(selectedListItem);
                    }
                }
                mode.finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        customListViewAdapter.removeSelection();
    }
});
```

Adapter code:

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

    Context context;
    private SparseBooleanArray selectedListItemsIds;
    List multipleSelectionList;

    public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId, List items) {
        super(context, resourceId, items);
        this.context = context;
        selectedListItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
        this.multipleSelectionList = items;
    }
    /*private view holder class*/
    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imgCountryFlag;
        TextView txtCountryName;
        TextView txtCountryCode;
        ImageButton click;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        SmsClass rowItem = (SmsClass) getItem(position);

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate( R.layout.list_item_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtCountryCode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.txtCountryName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            holder.click = (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById( R.id.click);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        holder.txtCountryCode.setText(rowItem.getBody());
        holder.txtCountryName.setText(rowItem.getNumberInside());
        return convertView;
    }

    public void remove(SmsClass object) {
        multipleSelectionList.remove(object);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void toggleSelection(int position) {
        selectView(position, !selectedListItemsIds.get(position));
    }

    public void removeSelection() {
        selectedListItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void selectView(int position, boolean value) {
        if (value)
            selectedListItemsIds.put(position, value);
        else
            selectedListItemsIds.delete(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public int getSelectedCount() {
        return selectedListItemsIds.size();
    }

    public SparseBooleanArray getSelectedIds() {
        return selectedListItemsIds;
    }
}
```

Comment: is it working without imageButton?

Comment: @SachinSingh yes. without image button I can select multi rows and delete them but when I add an image button, not working ...   any idea can help. tnx

Comment: It is not working because you are setting MultiChoiceModeListener on listView not on ImageButton. And You can not set it to ImageButton.  So to solve your problem try to set onClickListner in imageButton inside getView and call convertView.performOnClick()

Comment: @SachinSingh can I have the code, please. I can't understand. It's very important to me.

Comment: Its one line modification. Give me your adaptor code . I will modify .

Comment: @SachinSingh I add it in post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer :
we have to set

```
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

in root list item element and set

```
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

in the `ImageButton` view.

Answer (score -1):

**I am adding onClickListner in your getView method ..Please Try it**

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    SmsClass rowItem = (SmsClass) getItem(position);

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate( R.layout.list_item_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtCountryCode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.txtCountryName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        holder.click = (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById( R.id.click);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    holder.txtCountryCode.setText(rowItem.getBody());
    holder.txtCountryName.setText(rowItem.getNumberInside());
    holder.click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              convertView.performClick();
            }
        });
    return convertView;
}
```